# When using ExtJS Theming System, Why do I need to run sencha app build while Running sencha app watch?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I noticed that updating scss files while `sencha app watch` is running does not update the output CSS files correctly. I tried changing the parameters on the mixin I am using but the CSS output file's Modified Date in the file system is not updated. Even though I noticed that `sencha app watch` detects the changes the output is not correct (ie: I don't see the style being reflected in the UI).

I have to manually run `sencha app build development` just to ensure that the theme is built correctly.

Is this a normal behavior from Sencha CMD or I might have updated some config somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal. If you change `scss` files you need to run a build. Otherwise changes are not reflected in `css` files. Build is not triggered by `sencha app watch` since it can take tens of seconds, and the point of `watch` is to reflect changes in your code almost immediately (hot refresh).

The same goes for adding new classes with `Ext.define`, although in this case a `sencha app refresh` command is enough.

EDIT: according to the [documentation](https://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/guides/core_concepts/classic_theming.html#core_concepts-_-classic_theming_-_setup), `sencha app watch --fashion` updates the styles when changed.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Can you point me to the documentation about this or you know this from experience?

Comment: Experience, also I received some time ago a guide from Sencha Support to upgrade font scss files and it contains this instruction as well.

Comment: But now that you ask I became curious. Please refer [here](https://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/guides/core_concepts/classic_theming.html), it says that either you make the build or you use `sencha app watch --fashion`

Comment: So maybe it is possible to live update changes in scss also and my answer is not correct. Please try this.

Comment: The page you mentioned actually said "or run the `sencha app build --development` command to compile your styles" . I missed this part of the docs and assumed that `sencha app watch` compiles the styles in real time :D. I will give `--fashion` command a try again, I noticed that this has been clunky for me, but the docs claimed that it builds the styles instantly.

Comment: So it works? Then I'll edit my answer.